Pausar a execução de um for
Gostaria de saber se tem como eu determinar o tempo entre um enlace e outro do for. Por exemplo.
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   console.log("Número"+i);
}

a cada vez que ele for aumentar o valor de i, ele levar 1 segundo. Ou então pausar a execução por determinado tempo.
Tentei com setTimeout, setInterval, mas não deu certo.

No link indicado acima no box azul tem uma resposta que vc pode adaptar facilmente pro seu caso: em vez de subtrair, vc soma, para quando o valor for 5 e muda o tempo para 1000 milissegundos. Algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/v4sdk0b1/
